# Disable back button in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

How can I disable the back button in Jetpack Compose? I don't want the user to go back to previous screen.

I tried below code but the user can still go back to the previous screen:

```
BackHandler(enabled = false) {
   // do nothing
}
```

Comment: Could you verify it's in rootView?

Comment: i'm building 4 steps screen flow, after user completing the second one , I don't want them to go back

Comment: if you're using compose navigation, this code should be placed inside the active destination

Comment: i'm using compose navigation,  but I'm not clear what you mean by "active destination"

Comment: But I guess you should set `enabled = true` in order for your "do nothing" `BackHandler` to work and capture back presses (and do nothing)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should set `enabled` to `true` for taking control of back button. Then call `BackHandler` from the `current destination` in your `NavHost`

```
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = startDestination
) {

    composable(
        route = "Your Destination Route"
    ) {

        BackHandler(true) {
            // Or do nothing
            Log.i("LOG_TAG", "Clicked back")
        }

        YourDestinationScreen()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer disables back navigation by consuming all back navigation events. If you still want to handle back in another composables then you can use this approach:

```
@Composable
fun DisableBackHandler(
    isDisabled: Boolean,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        values = LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner.current?.let { parentDispatcherOwner ->
            arrayOf(
                LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner provides if (isDisabled) {
                    DummyOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner(parentDispatcherOwner.lifecycle)
                } else {
                    parentDispatcherOwner
                },
            )
        } ?: arrayOf(),
        content = content,
    )
}

private class DummyOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner(
    override val lifecycle: Lifecycle,
) : OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner {
    override val onBackPressedDispatcher: OnBackPressedDispatcher
        get() = OnBackPressedDispatcher()
}
```

It disables back handling for only part of your composition.